# Reading secrets from Vault CLI

Tags: command-line-interface, hashicorp-vault, vault

I'm trying to read secrets from Vault using CLI using the following commands:

```
JWT=$(cat /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token)
vault write auth/kubernetes/login role="${K8S_ROLE_IDENTIFIER}" jwt="${JWT}"
```

When calling `vault write`, I am getting the following:

```
'Error writing data to auth/kubernetes/login: Error making API request.\n'
'URL: PUT https://...:8200/v1/auth/kubernetes/login\n'
'Code: 400. Errors:\n'
'* missing client token\n'
```

The token is actually there. I was able to `echo` `JWT` but I am still getting missing client token error.

Any ideas?

Thank you!

Comment: The error is referencing the token for Vault client authentication. Did you authenticate before attempting to create the Kubernetes authentication engine role?

Comment: @MattSchuchard ah good point, actually I didn't :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the solution:

```
VAULT_TOKEN=$(vault write -format="json" \
  auth/"${VAULT_PATH}"/login \
  role="${K8S_ROLE_IDENTIFIER}" \
  jwt="${JWT}" \
  | jq -r '.auth["client_token"]')
```

Comment: no need to use `jq` .. just use `-field` option.. check my answer

Comment: interesting @AbdennourTOUMI! Thanks for sharing!

Comment: Then React with the answer :)  https://stackoverflow.com/a/73453378/747579

Answer (score 1):

In this situation, the thrown error message is not referring to the JSON Web Token. The error message is referring to the lack of Vault client authentication. This authentication, regardless of method, eventually involves generating a bound token for authentication.

To remedy this error, you need to authenticate your Vault client with a token or other method. This authentication also requires an attached policy which would authorize enabling the Kubernetes authentication engine, or else the next error will be authorization related.

Comment: I was able to do this reading client_token from vault write and exporting to VAULT_TOKEN :)

Answer (score 0):

Optimizing solutions of briba, by using `-field=token` option instead of depending on another command like `jq` :

```bash
VAULT_TOKEN=$(vault write -format="json" \
  auth/"${VAULT_PATH}"/login \
  role="${K8S_ROLE_IDENTIFIER}" \
  jwt="${JWT}" -field=token)
```